# sort lines by the last "element" [non-csv text file]

Tags: bash, shell, sorting, text

for lines with same number of columns separated by a dot delimiter, like

```
aa.bb
cc.dd
...
```

it's easy to sort by last column

```
sort -t. -k2,2 file
```

if the text file have different "columns", like

```
aa.b.xb
cc.dd
xx.cc.aa
a.b.c.d.e
...
```

then how to sort the lines by the last "column"

```
xx.cc.aa
cc.dd
a.b.c.d.e
aa.b.xb
...
```

Comment: Please add your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: if two lines have the same value in the last column, is there a secondary field to sort on? and if duplicated then a tertiary?

Comment: @markp-fuso not that complicated for my case. but still appreciated if u would like to present a more general solution like a second key of last second  "column"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make use of the [Schwartzian transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform) in `bash`.

```
awk -F. '{print $NF "\t" $0}' file | sort -k1,1 | cut -f2-
```

- First extract the last column and prepend it to the line delimited by
  a tab character.
- Then sort the lines with the 1st (prepended) column.
- Finaly remove the 1st column with `cut` command.